# How do I make an object array of a derived class in its base class in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance

I've spent a lot of time looking online for an answer to my question and haven't found anything. Unfortunately, I must've fallen behind in my class.

I have an assignment that requires that I make a class of campus and that, "A Campus must have 2 arrays of each type of building (Academic,Recreation)"
(This may mean just 1 array each per building. 2 arrays total. The rest of the assignment instructions had other grammatical errors.)

I have 8 files. a .h and .cpp file for each class. Campus is the base class, Building is the derived class from Campus, and Academic and Recreational are derived from the Building class.

I get error **C2061** on the line where I declare the arrays in the **Campus.h** file.

Campus.h

```
#pragma once

class Campus
{
public:

    Campus();
    static const int maxPerBuildingType;

    void loadFile();
    void searchList();
    void searchName();

private:

    int numberOfAcademic, numberOfRecreation;
    void Display();

    Campus * campusArray = new  Academic [maxPerBuildingType]; //Error C2061
    Campus * RecreationalArray = new Recreational[maxPerBuildingType]; //Error C2061



};
```

Campus.cpp (Haven't implemented functions yet)

```
#include "Campus.h"

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int Campus::maxPerBuildingType = 7;        



Campus::Campus()
{
}

void loadFile()
{
}

void searchList()
{
}

void searchName()
{
}
```

Building.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Campus.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Building :
    public Campus
{
public:
    Building();
    Building(int _ID, string _name, string _description);

    int getID();
    void setID(int _ID);

    string getName();
    void setName(string _Name);

    string getDescription();
    void setDescription(string _Description);

    virtual void showFullDescription() = 0; 

private:
    int ID;
    string name;
    string description;
};
```

Academic.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Building.h"
class Academic :
    public Building
{
public:
    Academic();
    Academic(int _ID, string _name, string _description, int _numOfRooms);

    int getNumOfRooms();

    void setNumOfRooms(int _numOfRooms);

    virtual void showFullDescription();

private:
    int numOfRooms;
};
```

I may have some other mistakes in the code but I'm mainly looking to understand what I'm doing wrong when it comes to making the Academic and Recreation arrays in the Campus class that my assignment requires. It also says to make these private in the .h file. I'm not looking for someone to do my work for me, I just want to understand it, but as of now, I'm completely clueless on what to do.

Thanks anyone in advance for the help!

Comment: Compile time constant expressions have to have the value visible, so you need to set `maxPerBuildingType` in the header. Also, I'm not sure if you can stack in-class initializers and constructors. And this is a big one: your array is of a different type than the pointer to it. This should work AFAIK but only if you cast the pointer to the derived type before using pointer arithmetic. If `sizeof(Camous) != sizeof(Academic)`, `campusArray[1]` is going to be interesting (bad). Also, please put the full error in your question along with the shortest code: [mcve].

Comment: At what line of the code is the error C2061 occurred? Do you have `Recreational` class? Are `Academic.h` and `Recreational.h` included in `Campus.h`? However even if you include them you will get cyclic dependency. You can not define `Campus` with initialization of both `campusArray` and `RecreationalArray` since classes they're uses could not be defined without `Campus`. You need to move the initialization of them to the constructor definition in `Campus.cpp`.

Comment: The error C2061 occurs in these 2 lines    `Campus * campusArray = new  Academic [maxPerBuildingType];` and
   `Campus * RecreationalArray = new Recreational[maxPerBuildingType];`. I don't have Academic.h or Recreational.h included in Campus.h

Comment: `Building` being derived from `Campus` does not make any sense .. inheritance should represent an "is-a" relationship.Surely you just have one campus that contains several buildings (as opposed to each building being its own campus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use initialization of `campusArray` and `recreationalArray` in class declaration like so

```
Campus * campusArray = new  Academic [maxPerBuildingType];
Campus * recreationalArray = new Recreational[maxPerBuildingType];
```

The reason is that to use initialization you need to declare `Academic` and `Recreational` classes before `Campus` class and you can not do this because they inherit from `Campus`.

However you can move the initialization to the `.cpp` file, so you `Campus.h` will look like

```
class Campus
{
public:
    static const int maxPerBuildingType;        

    Campus();
    void loadFile();
    void searchList();
    void searchName();
private:
    int numberOfAcademic, numberOfRecreation;
    void Display();
    Campus * campusArray;
    Campus * recreationalArray;
};
```

And the `Campus.cpp` becomes (other functions ommited)

```
#include "Campus.h"
#include "Academic.h"
#include "Recreational.h"

const int Campus::maxPerBuildingType = 7;        

Campus::Campus()
{
    campusArray = new Academic[maxPerBuildingType];
    recreationalArray = new Recreational[maxPerBuildingType];
}
```

Also this could be solved if you remove inheritance of `Campus` from `Building`, so that your `Academic` and `Recreational` classes would not be dependent on `Campus`. Then you can change the declaration of the `Campus` to

```
class Campus
{
public:
    static const int maxPerBuildingType;        

    Building* campusArray = new Academic[maxPerBuildingType];
    Building* recreationalArray = new Recreational[maxPerBuildingType];
};
```

Also in this case don't foget to include `Academic.h` and `Recreational.h` to `Campus.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Are those defined as global functions?

Campus.cpp

```
void loadFile()
void searchList()
void searchName()
```

Aren't these?
↓

```
void Campus::loadFile()
void Campus::searchList()
void Campus::searchName()
```